# map declared online no 65 and i want to add data into it but a firebase update Doc error i.e Function updateDoc() called with invlid data is coming

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am unable to push any data into my map in typescript

i used set method to add an entry into the map named users but it is giving error

line no 65-declared the map
line no 80-tried to add the value into the map using set method
line no 83 called and update Doc function from service in which reference to collection is passed and data we want to update with the field[[this is where update doc has been called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhQU9.png) ][[this is where map has been declared and data has been pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpTNu.png)]

error->
Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Map object (found in field users in document sources/noida/destinations/delhi)

```
users: Map<string, Number>=new Map<string,number>(); 
async book_seat(i:number){

  if(this.signInservice.IsLoggedIn()){
    var tot_no_of_seats=this.buses_details_arr[i].seats;
    if(tot_no_of_seats>=this.bookingForm.value.seats!){
      var rem_seats=tot_no_of_seats-this.bookingForm.value.seats!;
      var seats_req=this.bookingForm.value.seats!;
      
      (await this.signInservice.getCurrentUser()).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res?.displayName);

        this.name =res!.displayName as string;
      })

      this.users.set("aman",seats_req);
      
      this.services.updateDoc("sources/"+this.user_query.value.source+"/destinations/"+this.user_query.value.destination,{seats:rem_seats});
      this.services.updateDoc("sources/"+this.user_query.value.source+"/destinations/"+this.user_query.value.destination,{users:this.users});
      alert(`successfully booked ${this.bookingForm.value.seats} seats`);
    }
  }
}

}
```